# Monitoring general keyboard shortcuts in Windows (Ex. Ctrl twice to bring up Google Desktop Search)?

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Google Desktop Search has this nice feature of catching monitor shortcuts (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) while running in the background. Once the event is caught, the desktop search bar is being shown. Is there a way to simply implement this in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a [Global Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx).

This lets you preview keyboard events (and mouse events) before they are dispatched to the active application.